# excel VBA : how to skip blank cells between 2 cells that contain values?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working out a button that can auto sum value at column C that column A = column B
like the picture :
[PIC:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pKMW.png)
I can only copy the value in column C (that the word in column A = column B) to column E so far.

the code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim i As Integer, q As Integer

q = 2
For i = 3 To 100


Range("E" & q).Value = Range("b" & 3).Value

If Range("B" & i).Value = "A-RDL1" And Range("c" & i).Value = "OPEN" Then

Range("E" & i).Value = Range("d" & i).Value


End If
Next i


End Sub
```

the question 1) is how can I skip the blanks E9 to E17, so the numbers can be continuous? (AFTER CLICK THE BOTTON)
    question 2) is it possible to auto sum the Numbers in column E instead of show each?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my poor English...

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you can skip those, just carry out a check in the cell value and compare to empty string: `Range("").Value2 = ""`. I personally prefer to do it like this though, to avoid false positives: `Len(Trim(Range("").Value2)) = 0`.

2) Yes, you can do that. just declare an Integer variable or two and use that to carry out a running count of your values.